# Understanding the math behind the code

Tags: c, math

I have a really basic and simple question but I am having problems with understanding this C code.

```
#define POLYNOMIAL(x) \
(((((3.0 * (x) + 2.0) * (x) - 5.0) * (x) - 1.0) * (x) + 7.0) * (x) - 6.0)
```

This definition is for this polynomial: 3x<sup>5</sup>+2x<sup>4</sup>-5x<sup>3</sup>-x<sup>2</sup>+7x-6

How can I convert this polynomial into the form shown in the `#define`? Is there any trick for this?

Comment: Take a look at the [`pow()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_pow.htm) function in C.

Comment: Forget C for a minute. Write that expression down and start expanding the terms.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method

Comment: Not related to programming (or a specific PL), but a mathematical problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your polynomial:

> 3x<sup>5</sup> + 2x<sup>4</sup> - 5x<sup>3</sup> - x<sup>2</sup> + 7x - 6

Can be rewritten successively:

> (3x<sup>4</sup> + 2x<sup>3</sup> - 5x<sup>2</sup> - x + 7) · x - 6
>   ((3x<sup>3</sup> + 2x<sup>2</sup> - 5x - 1) · x + 7) · x - 6
>   (((3x<sup>2</sup> + 2x - 5) · x - 1) · x + 7) · x - 6
>   ((((3x + 2) · x - 5) · x - 1) · x + 7) · x - 6

This an expanded, or *unrolled*, Horner's Method loop. If the coefficients were expressed as an array:

```
double polynomial[] = { -6, 7, -1, -5, 2, 3 };
```

Then, the polynomial could be evaluated with this function:

```
double horners (double poly[], int terms, double x) {
    double result = 0;
    while (terms--) {
        result = result * x + poly[terms];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add parenthesis and decrease out powers inside until you get to the last one, like this:

```
(3x^5)+(2x^4)-(5x^3)-(x^2)+7x-6
((3x^4)+(2x^3)-(5x^2)-x+7)x-6
(((3x^3)+(2x^2)-5x-1)x+7)x-6
((((3x^2)+2x-5)x-1)x+7)x-6
((((3x+2)x-5)x-1)x+7)x-6
```